# Book about a group of teenagers who start dying one by one (features a disfiguring acid attack on one of the girls)

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

I read this book 10+ years ago and I think it was old then.
It is about a group of teenagers (boys and girls) and they start dying one by one. One girl gets hit in the face with acid and it disfigures her. Another boy (the last surviving one) is romantically involved with this girl and it turns out she’s an alien (I think a worm) from another planet and very evil.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

Could it be Christopher Pike's *[The Star Group](http://likepike.blogspot.com/2008/10/star-group.html)*?

> The back of the book description says: "There are seven of them, three guys and four girls. Driven to return to a lonely spot where tragedy struck before". Then it goes on to mention alien contact

Shena has her face mangled by acid before the events of the book (later discovered to be engineered by one of the other characters). All of the teenagers are revealed to actually be aliens (sort of... it's one of Christopher Pike's more muddled books, and the alien souls have been reincarnated on Earth in human bodies). As noted, they do start dying off one by one, with Gale, who Dan has been sleeping with (well, turns out Gale has been sleeping with *everyone*) turning out to be evil and causing Dan to kill himself, and then Shena turning out to have engineered the whole thing to counter Gale. The animal imagery used is reptilian, though, with Gale describing Shena's acid scarring as making her skin scaley.

> Dan compares Gale to a snake. Gale says that she mangled Shena's face on purpose so she would look scaly and Dan would suspect her of being the evil reptile and not Gale.

I remembered Pike's *[Monster](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/170160/sci-fi-horror-book-where-alien-microorganisms-turn-humans-into-aliens/170171#170171)* turning out to be about alien creatures living in human bodies, so I figured it was worth a try, and a search for `"christopher pike" acid face alien` brought up the linked review.